# Passing enum in params

Tags: c#, enums, parameters

How can I pass an enum as one of the parameters of the method? I only need in some implementations of the method, and not in others. That's how method declaration looks:

```
public abstract void SomeMethod(params object[] someParams);
```

And that's how I would like some of the implementations to look:

```
public override void SomeMethod(params object[] someParams) {

    SomeEnum someEnum = someParams[0];
    if (someEnum == null)
        return;

}
```

This code, of course, is invalid, but it shows what I intend to do. Other implementations of the method may use other enums, or use no enums at all.

*Update:* As many have stated, it's a very strange thing to do, throwin type-safety out of the window. So, I decided to explain why I'm doing this.

I have to pass method calls to a lot of various subclasses of a class where I declare this method through a system that sends them across a network (as well as locally) and executes them at specific time in a special order. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public override void SomeMethod(params object[] someParams)
{
    if (!(someParms[0] is SomeEnum))
        return;

    var se = (SomeEnum) someParams[0];
    ...
}
```

Though quite why you wouldd want to do this over an explicitly typed parameter I cannot imagine.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass enum values of a type using the `params` keyword just as any other object.

```
public override void SomeMethod(params SomeEnum[] someEnums) 
{
     foreach(SomeEnum e in someEnums)
     {

     }
}
```

---

In case you gotta pass other enums as well to this method, you could use `System.Enum` as parameter since all enums derive from it. Slightly stronger typing.

```
public override void SomeMethod(params Enum[] enums) 
{
    //something like
    var @enum = enums[0];
    if (!(@enum is SomeEnum))
        return;

    var someEnum = (SomeEnum)@enum;
}
```

---

As to acknowledge your edit, the best way is to specify the objects you are going to pass during method call explicitly as the signature of your method. Only if the number of parameters you will pass have to be variable, you should rely on `params` keyword. Otherwise, you should stick to explicitly declaring the signature. If your enum `SomeEnum` is optional, you can declare it at last as an optional parameter. Like this:

```
public override void SomeMethod(int a, string b, SomeEnum? someEnum = null) 
{
    if (someEnum == null)
       //handle the logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like you're really asking for trouble here, basically removing any sort of strong typing from the signature. You'll need to cast.

Secondly, a value of type `SomeEnum` can never be null, because enums are value types. So you *could* write:

```
public override void SomeMethod(params object[] someParams)
{
    if (someParams[0] == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    // This will throw an exception if you've been given the wrong kind
    // of argument. I prefer that to just silently returning, as it would
    // usually indicate a programming error which should be fixed.
    SomeEnum someEnum = (SomeEnum) someParams[0];
    ...    
}
```

However, you'd be better off working out a way of representing the parameters in a more strongly typed way. Unfortunately, we can't really help you do that without more information.

Comment: I have to pass method calls through a system that sends them across a network (as well as locally) and executes them at specific time in a special order. Is there a better way to do this? (Included this comment in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I think normally you'd use overloads for different implementations of the method, not overrides, if they require different parameters.  These could still have params at the end:

```
void M(SomeEnum someEnum, params object[] someParams)
{
   //...
```

Your code could work with this signature, too, however:

```
public override void SomeMethod(params object[] someParams) {

    if (someParams.Length == 0 or !(someParams[0] is SomeEnum))
        return;

    SomeEnum someEnum = (SomeEnum)someParams[0];
    //...
```